# How to re-initialize Tensorflow session

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am optimising a Tensorflow/Keras model in Jupyter Notebook.

Some of `fit` runs fall into not learning (`nan` for loss and acc).

After `nan` occurred, if I just try to re-run cells to create model and train it again - it will always be `nan`.

If I restart kernel next run most likely works fine.

**Is there a static variable somewhere in TF/Keras I need to reset without restarting kernel?**

**EDIT**: I use this code routinely before building model and it does not solve my problem.

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

**EDIT2:** this is TPU model. Its possible that setting weights on TPU model has a bug.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe different initializations lead into getting `nan`?

Comment: I am almost sure that specific weights combination leads to nan. But my problem is that - if I get nan at first run - then only Kernel restart fixes that.. What I need is to be able to rerun just model creation cell and `fit` cell.. So I need some python code to reset random generator or some TF or Keras variables which affect the weights

Comment: What if you do `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` and then set the random seed `tf.set_random_seed(42)`? Can you get reproducible results then?

Comment: I will try once I catch another nan. Good idea. Thank you

Comment: no setting random seed didn't help.. something else is in play..

Comment: Does the loss become nan immediately or after you train for some time?

Comment: close to beginning.. sometime almost immediate, sometime within 1 min (out of 10min total)

Comment: There is an option that your gradients explode as the training progresses from time to time? Have to tried using a really low learning rate and clipping the gradients? That may fix the problem permanently.

Comment: LR is 0.0001 for adam. I don't know how to clip gradients.. but wait a sec.. the question is rather how to restart training without shutting kernel completely, because whatever it is - it will repeat once it happened on 1st run and will not if I restart the kernel.

Comment: I thought that maybe restarting the kernel helps coincidentally. But anyways, what happens is pretty weird..

Comment: no worries. probably TPU bug when it doesn't clear some variables which influence weight settings.. TF TPU support is pretty patchy..

Comment: Can you give a brief description of your setup? Without any description of the architecture, it would be hard to explain whats causing the issue.Also I think sometimes the model is encountering bad inputs which might also be a cause for you getting Nan values as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2134#issuecomment-268628635)

Comment: I'll edit my question with more details. But I can rule out bad data now. All my variables with data and everything else are the same for each run. That's a fact.